# template enforcing unnecessary restriction

Tags: c++, templates

Say an Object has a templated TYPE (for a very good reason)

```
template <typename T> class Object {
};
```

I want an Object to be able to contain an array of subobjects.

```
template <typename T> class Object {
  vector< Object<T>* > subobjects;
};
```

However, the subobjects CAN BE OF ANY TYPE. That is, a subobject can be an Object of a different T than it’s parent.

The language is enforcing a restriction that doesn’t need to be there. How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you want to be able to do with `subobjects`, once you somehow manage to define it the way you want? Is there something common to all instantiations of `Object`?

Comment: Without knowing what you're really trying to achieve, it's hard to say.  But one obvious (but I haven't tested) possibility is  `template<typename T, typename U> class Object {std::vector<Object<U> > subobjects;};`

Comment: One typical way to allow this is to create new base class that contains that part of `Object`'s interface that does not depend on `T` and extend `Object` from that. Then `subobjects` can hold pointers to this base class.

Comment: @Peter that means restricting subobjects to all being type U, but I need them to be _mixed_ types (for example you need to be able to have a float, int, and double subobject in the same array)

Comment: That's simply not possible without some abstraction. In this case, it's not even templates imposing an "arbitrary" restriction. It's a lack of what I would consider foundational knowledge.

Comment: So you want a variant type.  Look up `std::variant`.

Answer (score 4):

A template is a type-factory.  `Object<int>` and `Object<double>` are **unrelated types**.

`Object<int>` generates one type, and `Object<double>` generates a different type.

If you want these two types to be related, you can make them related.

```
struct IObject {
  virtual ~IObject() {}
  // common interface
};
```

then

```
template<class T>
struct Object<T>:IObject {
  std::vector<IObject*> subObjects;
};
```

now your `Object<T>` has subobjects.  All the code knows (statically) is that they are `IObject`s.

---

Now, if you want the type `T` to be runtime determined, you could use `std::any` (this has type safety issues, sort of; it is "brittle" in that the reader needs to know the exact type that went into it) or `std::variant<double, int, std::string>` (but here you have to name all of the supported types).

---

Basically, you are probably using a round peg and a square hole.

You have a problem.  You thought templates where the solution.  You found a problem with your solution.  You looked for a way to make templates work.

Comment: The toy example may look square-peg-round-hole but I assure you the problem this applies to looks pretty cool with this solution

Comment: @bobobobo, if you are (say) doing json wrappers in C++, just say so.  I've seen a thousand (ok, at least a hundred) "I want polymorphism" where the person tries to use the wrong kind of polymorphism in C++.  Ask a question describing your _actual underlying problem_ as well as your attempted solution and what went wrong (the fact that `Object<T>*` can't be polymorphic isn't the underlying problem; the underlying problem is why you want `Object<T>*` to be polymorphic).  (do this via the [ask question] button, not here in these comments).

Answer (score 1):

> The language is enforcing a restriction that doesn’t need to be there. How do I fix this?

The language isn't enforcing anything. You wrote a template with one type parameter, so that parameter can only take one value at a time.

> However, the subobjects CAN BE OF ANY TYPE. That is, a subobject can be an Object of a different T than it’s parent.

If you mean each `Object<T>` can have children of a single different type `U != T`, just write

```
template <typename T, typename U> class Object {
  vector< Object<U>* > subobjects;
};
```

If you mean each object can have children of a variety of instantiations, you either need some form of type erasure (eg. [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)), or polymorphism.

In either case, you need to give some thought to what you're going to *do* with these things you don't know the concrete type of. How will you use them? This is the information needed to choose the appropriate mechanism.

Comment: `Object<U>` is not valid there.

Answer (score 0):

Using @WayneVanderLinde's comment:

```
struct Object{
  vector<Object*> subobjects;
};

template<typename T> struct TObject : public Object {};
```

you can now create

```
TObject<int> i;
TObject<double>* d = new TObject<double>();
i.subobjects.push_back( d );
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and your answer does not make it any more clear.

Comment: @super That doesn't seem to be match what other people who have answered think

Comment: Yeah, even thought I didn't downvote your question it still has -1 score. That speaks for itself. Just because one person went out of their way to guess what you actually wanted and was close enough that it helped you doesn't magically make your question any better. Maybe you should revisit the [help] to read up on how to ask.